# Update multiple values in a sequence

Tags: scala, collections, immutability

To get a sequence with one value updated, one can use

```
seq.updated(index, value)
```

I want to set a new value for a range of elements. Is there a library function for that? I currently use the following function:

```
def updatedSlice[A](seq: List[A], ind: Iterable[Int], value: A): List[A] = 
    if (ind.isEmpty) seq
    else updatedSlice(seq.updated(ind.head, value), ind.tail, value)
```

Besides the need of writing function, this seems to be inefficient, and also works only for lists, rather than arbitrary subclasses of `Seq` and `String`s. So,

- is there a method that performs it?
- how can I parametrize the function to take (and return) some subclass of `Seq[A]`?

Comment: I don't have access to a computer right now, but if I remember correctly the `.patch` method might be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there's no combinator that directly provides this functionality.

For the `Seq` part, well, it works only for `List` because you're taking a `List` as a parameter. Take a `Seq`, return a `Seq` and you already have one less problem.

Moreover, your implementation throws an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception if `ind` contains an index greater or equal to the `seq` length.

Here's an alternative implementation (which uses `Set` for a O(1) `contains`)

```
def updatedAtIndexes[A](seq: Seq[A], ind: Set[Int], value: A): Seq[A] = seq.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (el, i) if ind.contains(i) => value
  case (el, _) => el
}
```

Example

```
updatedAtIndexes(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Set(0, 2), 42) // List(42, 2, 42, 4)
```

---

You can even make it prettier with a simple implicit class:

```
implicit class MyPimpedSeq[A](seq: Seq[A]) {
  def updatedAtIndexes(ind: Set[Int], value: A): Seq[A] = seq.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (el, i) if ind.contains(i) => value
    case (el, _) => el
  }
}
```

Examples

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).updatedAtIndexes(Set(0, 2), 42) // List(42, 2, 42, 4)
Vector(1, 2, 3).updatedAtIndexes(Set(1, 2, 3), 42) // Vector(1, 42, 42)
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice implementations, but they don’t address neither of my questions. Is there a way to define the method signature to return List when I pass a List, and Vector if I pass a Vector? With your implementations I need to cast them explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

No one at a computer has said:

```
scala> (1 to 10).toSeq patch (3, (1 to 5), 3)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Save your green checks for @Marth.

Note they're still working on it.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8474

Which says something about less-frequently-used API.

Update: I glanced at the question a second time and saw that I misread it, oh well:

```
scala> implicit class x[A](as: Seq[A]) {
     | def updatedAt(is: collection.Traversable[Int], a: A) = {
     | (as /: is) { case (xx, i) => xx updated (i, a) } } }
defined class x

scala> (1 to 10) updatedAt (Seq(3,6,9), 0)
res9: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 0)
```

Just a relaxing round of golf.

Update: s/relaxing/annoying

Looks like it needs more type params, but I don't have a time slice for it.

```
scala> implicit class slicer[A, B[_] <: Seq[_]](as: B[A]) {
     | def updatedAt[That<:B[_]](is: Traversable[Int], a: A)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[B[A], A, That]) =
     | (as /: is) { case (x,i) => x updated[A,That] (i,a) }}
<console>:15: error: type arguments [A,That] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of
 value updated: [B >: _$1, That](index: Int, elem: B)(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[_$1],B,That])That <and> [B >: A, That](index: Int, elem: B)(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That])That
       (as /: is) { case (x,i) => x updated[A,That] (i,a) }}
                                    ^
```

Who even knew updated was overloaded?

My new favorite Odersky quote:

> I played with it until it got too tedious.

Comment: nice implementation, just note that the `updateAt` method can still throw an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception: `(1 to 10) updatedAt (Seq(10), 0)`

Comment: Thx for the note. I would probably put it in the scaladoc, since `(1 to 10).toArray update (10, 0)` also throws; it's only natural.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `patch`; it can be used in the particular case when `ind` is a range (which I actually needed). Your latter implementation returns `Seq` regardless of what type I pass, while I asked for a generic version (e.g. I need to update a List and get a List as result, avoiding casts).

Comment: Maybe @GabrielePetronella will take a swing at the type params at lunch. (Unless it's already lunch.)